# Typescript: Typing a variable that will have a type assigned to it

Tags: typescript

Have a question about typing a variable that will have a type assigned to it.

EG:

```
interface HTTPClient { … }
class BrowserHTTPClient implements HTTPClient { … }
class NodeHTTPClient implements HTTPClient { … }

let HTTPClientType: ********;

if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  HTTPClientType = NodeHTTPClient;
} else {
  HTTPClientType = BrowserHTTPClient;
}
```

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to type a variable as a type. I do not see this in the Typescript docs.

What do I replace ******* with, is this supported by typescript, do I need to make a factory?

Comment: How are you going to use `HTTPClientType`? Is it the type or the class that you want?

Comment: The type, so I can make many instances of it.

Comment: If you want to make instances of it, you need the class, not the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a factory via a constructor interface:

```
export interface HTTPClientConstructor {
  new(baseUrl: string): HTTPClient;
}
interface HTTPClient { … }
class BrowserHTTPClient implements HTTPClient { … }
class NodeHTTPClient implements HTTPClient { … }

let HTTPClientFactory: HTTPClientConstructor;

if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  HTTPClientFactory = NodeHTTPClient;
} else {
  HTTPClientFactory = BrowserHTTPClient;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do this:

```
let httpClientType: typeof BrowserHTTPClient | typeof NodeHTTPClient;

if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  httpClientType = NodeHTTPClient;
} else {
  httpClientType = BrowserHTTPClient;
}

var httpClient = new httpClientType();
```

**Clarifications**

```
class BrowserHTTPClient {  }

// myObject should be of the type BrowserHTTPClient
// For example an instance of BrowserHTTPClient, but not necessarily as long as it's structurally compatible with the type BrowserHTTPClient
let myObj: BrowserHTTPClient;

// myClass should be the class BrowserHTTPClient (Or rather, it should fulfill the type of the class of the type BrowserHTTPClient, hence it can be any object that has the same structure as the _class_ BrowserHTTPClient. Inception warning here, see explanation of structural typing below.)
let myClass: typeof BrowserHTTPClient;

// make a instance of myClass (BrowserHTTPClient)
myClass = BrowserHTTPClient; // Here, myClass IS the class BrowserHTTPClient.
myObj = new myClass();
```

**Class vs Type**

In nominatively typed languages, like C#, a `class` and a `type` is practically the same thing. If you say that a variable is of some type, the variable can't be anything else than an instance of that specific class or, if the type comes from an interface, a class that implements that specific interface.

This is not the same in TypeScript that is structurally typed, and the concepts `class` and `type` are further apart. If you define a class in typescript, that will also create a type. But when you define a variable to be of that type, it could be set to anything that fulfills that type.

```
class MyClass {
    public Name: string;
}

class MyOtherClass {
    public Name: string;
    public Age: number;
}

let obj: MyClass;

obj = new MyClass();
obj = new MyOtherClass(); // Also ok, since it fulfills the type MyClass (It has a field Name that is a string)
```

Comment: What if I only care that the type implements an interface? From what I can tell `let HTTPClientType: typeof HTTPClient;` is invalid. Because `HTTPClient` is an interface and therefore not a type.

Comment: @squirly HTTPClient is also a type, that is created by the interface HTTPClient,  but you can not do typeof on it since it is not a class. If you only want something to be of the type HTTPClient, just use the type as it is.

Comment: But if you want to use it for making instances, it needs to be a class. And if it is, your other classes can inherit it.

Comment: When using typeof like this (not to be confused with typeof [Variable] in runtime logic), the compiler assumes that what comes after is a class. So it's not doing typeof [Type], it's doing typeof [Class]. If you take away the typeof, it just references the type.